# Subviews alignment inside UILabel. Xamarin IOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, uilabel

In this code i am trying to add tapFields ( UIViews ) above specific words in UILabel. Width, Height, X and Y for each tapField are calculated correctly ( also for multiline text ). The problem is that x and y are ignored for all fields and they all turn out to be in the upper left corner of MessageLabel :(

As I managed to understand - it happens because of the fact that MessageLabel.Frame is (0,0,0,0) But I do not know how to fix it.

```
public CGRect getTapRectForError(NSMutableAttributedString text, NSRange range, float maxWidth)
    {
        var textStorage = new NSTextStorage();
        textStorage.SetString(text);
        var textContainer = new NSTextContainer(new CGSize(4000, 400));
        var layoutManager = new NSLayoutManager();
        layoutManager.AddTextContainer(textContainer);
        textStorage.AddLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        textContainer.LineFragmentPadding = 0;
        var glyphRange = layoutManager.GlyphRangeForCharacterRange(range);
        var glyphRect = layoutManager.BoundingRectForGlyphRange(range, textContainer);

        return glyphRect;
    }

    protected void OnViewTapped(UIGestureRecognizer sender)
    {
        var a = 1;
    }

    public BubbleCell SetupErrors(BubbleCell cell, NSIndexPath indexPath, GrammarCheckResultJson errors)
    {
        if (errors.errors != null)
        {
            var labelText = new NSMutableAttributedString(cell.MessageLabel.Text, underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.Single);

            var Attributes = new UIStringAttributes
            {
                ForegroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(255, 230, 58),
                UnderlineColor = UIColor.FromRGB(255, 230, 58),
            };

            foreach (ErrorJson error in errors.errors)
            {
                labelText.AddAttributes(Attributes.Dictionary, new NSRange(error.offset, error.length));
                var glyphRect = getTapRectForError(labelText, new NSRange(error.offset, error.length), (float)error.length);
                UIView eView = new UIView(glyphRect);

                eView.AddGestureRecognizer(new UITapGestureRecognizer(OnViewTapped));

                cell.MessageLabel.AddSubview(eView);
            }

            cell.MessageLabel.AttributedText = labelText;
        }
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: where to call function `SetupErrors`  and where did you get MessageLabel.Frame is (0,0,0,0)

Comment: Already fixed : ) I'll update the topic soon